# Why is the YTD return for my 401k contributions down 20% but the YTD return on S&P500 is 1.5%?

Tags: united-states, investing, 401k

I imagined that my 401k investments must be going to some low-risk-stable-return type of financial investments. However, when I checked the YTD return on my 401k contributions for this year, it was down 20% while S&P500 is up 1.5% till month of June.

Does that mean that my 401k portfolio of investments is being managed extremely poorly?

Comment: "I imagined that my 401k investments must be going to some low-risk-stable-return type of financial investments." Um, why?

Comment: "S&P500 is up 1.5% till month of June"  It certainly is not.  Maybe you've confused the dividend yield with the YTD return?

Comment: To expand on the comment from @ronrothman: generally speaking you want longer term investments to be higher risk the further from the time you want them and lower risk as you get closer. If you're not close to retirement age, then you don't need to worry about movements up and down over shorter timescales, they will come out in the wash eventually and you'll end up with more than if you chose lower risk, lower return investments.

Comment: Why don't you know what your 401k is invested in? Every 401k I've been in has had a choice of investment funds, and I've always made choices based on my investment objectives. And even if you don't know what to choose, there should be a website where you can view your investments, and you should be getting periodic statements.

Comment: How old are you, how close are you to retirement, and what funds are you invested in and in what percentages? e.g. "I'm 32, I'm 35 years from retirement, and I'm invested 50% in Fidelity Total Index and 50% in Vanguard High Risk International" (making those up).

Comment: You may be tempted to sell it all - consider *not* doing this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The S&P 500 is not up 1.5% YTD.

The S&P 500 closed at 4766.18 on 12/31/2021.  Today, 6/15/2022, it closed at 3789.99.  This represents a 20.5% decline.  This does not include dividends, which complicate the math a bit, but would not throw these numbers off by more than about 1%.

Your 401(k) investments seem to be tracking the broader market.

Answer (score 7):

> Does that mean that my 401k portfolio of investments is being managed
> extremely poorly ?

I am only going to focus on this aspect of the question

> I imagined that my 401k investments must be going to some
> low-risk-stable-return type of financial investments.

Some companies have a default investment choice if the employee doesn't specify one. That default option could be an S&P 500 fund, or it could be a fund that has a target date that is geared to your age so that the investment would become more conservative as you get closer to retirement.

In any case the employee should make sure that their funds are invested the way they want.

Terms like low-risk-stable sound like you were expecting that all or most of the money was going into a bond fund.

> However, when I checked the YTD return on my 401k contributions for
> this year, it was down 20% while S&P500 is up 1.5% till month of June.

Comparing the return to the S&P 500 implies that you expected to compare your results to something that is 100% stocks. Stock funds are never low-risk or stable.

You need decide how risky you want you investments to be. You need to look at the funds available, look at their returns and their expense, and then decide to invest in a way that meets your needs.

The good thing about a 401(k), or an IRA, is that selling one fund and then buying another has no tax impact as long as the money is still in the 401(k) or IRA.

Comment: On the other hand, if OP's retirement is a ways into the future, they'd be better served with a higher risk / higher return type of financial instrument.